# Pulling linear transformations out of an integral?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am studying physics and in my mathematical methods course we were asked to do this integral:
$\int \dot{r} \times B \ dt$

The answer given is $(r \times B)+c$

This didnt seem to be obvious to me so I checked up online and apparently in general it is true that for any linear transformation you can pull it out of an integral and a cross product is a linear transformation.

I am still not too sure about why that is ok to do. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! The reason is that an integral is a linear transformation.

Comment: Hi, I understand that fact from checking online but I cant see why thats the case. Is there anyway of showing why or somewhere I can check to find a proof?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are working on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation and $v$ be a vector. Then we have that
$$(Tv)_i=\sum_{j}T_{ij}v_k$$
And if you define the integral of a vector as component-wise integral, then the $i$-th component of the integral will be
$$\int \sum_j T_{ij}v_j \mathrm{d}t$$
And if $T$ is independent of $t$, then we can use the finite additivity of the integral to get that the $i$-th component of the result is
$$\sum_j T_{ij}\int v_j \mathrm{d}t$$
And the residual integral is just the $j$-th component of the integral of $v$, so:
$$\sum_j T_{ij}\left(\int v \mathrm{d}t\right)_j$$
So in vector notation, the result is
$$T \int v \mathrm{d}t$$